# Deleting folder with rm -rf

Tags: linux, centos, ssh

I have a folder which name is `photo` and it is 13gb. I checked my HDD space with `df -h` command and it said you have 50GB free space. Then I deleted my `photo` folder with `rm -rf photo/` command. It deleted instantly. Now I am checking free space again with `df -h` command and it still says you have 50GB free space.

When I try to reach my `photo` folder i am getting

```
No such file or directory
```

Warning.

What can be cause to this problem? I am using Centos 6.5 x64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `photo` directory might have been a symlink, or been a directory containing symlinks, which would explain both why no space was reclaimed and how it deleted so fast.

Unfortunately if it was symlinks, then you've deleted the links that would have told you where the actual files were.
You can either search for the files yourself, or use `locate <filename>` if you can remember a filename, or `find / -name <filename>` if locate isn't installed.
Or you can use `du -xak / | sort -rn >/tmp/sizes` to find the largest files/directories on disk, but that will take quite a while and use lots of disk I/O.

Comment: What do you suggest?

Comment: Try running lsof / | grep deleted to see if there's a process holding locks on the folder (like pako suggested). If you do find a process like that, kill it.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/a7tgu6

Comment: That doesn't look like the command @Mugurel suggested.

Comment: Try ````lsof / | grep deleted```` instead of ````lsof / | grep thumb````

Answer (score 0):

The free space reported by df -h is not updated imediately after you delete some files. Try running:

`sync`

Also, if the files were opened by some processes, the inodes might still exists until the files are closed.

Comment: I tried sync command. Nothing changed.